# 404 fallback route in Express

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, routes

I am utterly confused by the seemingly bad documentation of Express. I want to archive a very simple thing: Return a custom 404 for every unmatched route in `express`. At first, this seems very straight forward:

```
app.get('/oembed', oembed()); // a valid route
app.get('/health', health()); // another one
app.get('*', notFound()); // catch everything else and return a 404
```

However, when a valid url has been opened (like `/oembed`) `express` continues to work through the routes and ends up calling `notFound()` *as well*. I still see my `/oembed` response but I get an error in the console saying `notFound()` is trying to set headers (`404`) when the body has already been sent.

I tried to implement a [middleware that catches errors](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) like this

```
function notFound() {
  return (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(404);
    next(err);
  };
}
```

and added it with `app.use(notFound());`, but this won't even get called. I find it hard to find anything on this on the internet (e.g. that is not outdated or wrong) and the official documentation does not seem to have anything specific for this very standard use case. I'm kind of stuck here and I don't know why.

Comment: How does your `/oembed` route look like?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/48424822c10633ac4bb5944ea6b8873b I commented the code where actual middleware stuff happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your implementation of `oembed`:

```
export default () => function oembed(req, res, next) {
  const response = loadResponseByQuery(req.query);

  response.onLoad()
    .then(() => response.syncWithS3())
    .then(() => response.setHeaders(res)) // sets headers
    .then(() => response.sendBody(res))   // sends body
    .then(() => next())                   // next()

    .catch(() => response.sendError(res))
    .catch(() => next());
};
```

It's calling `next` after sending the response body, which means that it will propagate the request to any following (matching) route handlers, including the `notFound()` handler.

With Express, `next` is generally only used to pass along a request if the current handler doesn't respond to it, or if doesn't know how to, or wants to, deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's the one.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [routes docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), we can use regex as path matcher

```js
app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send();
  //res.json({ status: ":(" });
});
```